# Instagram api return post link

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I am making gallery with Instagram images, and now I want to link my gallery, I want when user click on image, it suppose to redirect him on instagram post. So now I need to get link from instagram api. 
For now I have only pictures and I get it in this way :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + userid + '/media/recent',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
    success: function(data){ ........
```

So can someone help me how to get post URLs?

Comment: Are you looking for the urls of the images or the posts?

Comment: @TariqB. url of the posts. Sry my mistake

Comment: The link parameter in the data objects is supposed to be the URL to the post. Please try that.

Comment: @TariqB.can you help about syntax? data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos, URL} ?

Comment: You have to get the authorization code and token through Oauth and use that in this request.

Answer (score 2):

From [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/), you should use **link** parameter to obtain the link of each photo. This code should be inside **success(data)** function. Using ***/users/self/media/recent*** endpoint it will be probably called like that:

```
[...]
success: function(data){
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
        var photoURL = data[i].images.standard_resolution.url;
        var photoLink = data[i].link;
        var username = data[i].user.username;

        var html = "<a href='" + photoLink + "' target='_blank'>";
        html += "    <img src='" + photoURL + "' alt='" + username + "'>";
        html += "</a>";

        // here you should append this html code to some container box
        document.getElementById("myContainer").innerHTML += html;
    }
}
```

This code above was not tested. But I believe it's working fine.
And below are the [media object returned by Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/), so you can choose whichever info do you need. I hid users_in_photo and images section to facilitate comprehension.

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "image",
    "users_in_photo": [{...}],
    "filter": "Walden",
    "tags": [],
    "comments": { "count": 2 },
    "caption": null,
    "likes": { "count": 1 },
    "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
    "user": {
        "username": "kevin",
        "full_name": "Kevin S",
        "profile_picture": "...",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "created_time": "1279340983",
    "images": {...},
    "id": "3",
    "location": null
}
}
```

Users in photo section:

```
"users_in_photo": [{
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "full_name": "Kevin S",
            "id": "3",
            "profile_picture": "..."
        },
        "position": {
            "x": 0.315,
            "y": 0.9111
        }
    }],
```

Images section:

```
"images": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_6.jpg",
            "width": 306,
            "height": 306
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_5.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_7.jpg",
            "width": 612,
            "height": 612
        }
    },
```

Good luck!